# Exponential integral with power in square root

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I have been trying to solve an integral. I know that the solution exists for the form

$$1- \dfrac{2}{\mathcal{R}^2_{\mathcal{G}}}\int_{0}^{\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{G}}} \exp (-\Phi r^{\alpha}) r\, {\rm d}r,$$

where $\alpha>0, \mathcal{R}_\mathcal{G}>0$. However, I want to solve

> $$1- \dfrac{2}{\mathcal{R}^2_{\mathcal{G}}}\int_{0}^{\mathcal{R}_{\mathcal{G}}} \exp \left(-\Phi \left(\sqrt{r^2+h^2}\right)^{\alpha}\right) r\,  {\rm d}r,$$

where $\Phi>0$, $\alpha>0, \mathcal{R}_\mathcal{G}>0 $and $h>0$. Any clue please?

Comment: Please tell us your effort. Have you tried $t=\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$?

Comment: yes I have tried, but on substituting this, the lower limit of integral becomes -h and I checked Table of Integrals (3.351) for an equivalent solution but no hope. Infact the equations in 3.351 are for integer values of n but in my case the substitution may result in non negative values.